# checking if a.out exists then remove with make clean otherwise do try to remove -- Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, sh

I have this simple makefile, after running `make` command I get output `parser` that I runs like `#: ./parser` but sometimes it also generate `a.out` So when make doesn't generate a.out with last `make` command then running `make clean` gives warning that `rm: can not remove a.out, No such file or directory`

So I like my `make clean` command also check if a.out exists then remove otherwise dont try to remove. How can I do it in makefile inside `clean: ....`

```
parser: header.h parser.c
    gcc header.h parser.c -o parser
    
clean:
    rm parser a.out
```

Comment: `rm -f` to ignore missing files

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this except for the warning? You can use `rm -f` to remove that warning.

Comment: To precise other posts: Just replace the line 'rm parser a.out' by 'rm -f parser a.out'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing it is to remove by force:

```
clean:
    rm -f parser a.out
```

From `rm` manpage:

> -f, --force 
> ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

Comment: can U also please tell can I remove `parser.c` and `header.h` and just use implicit rules for `.c` and `.h` files. Can u please please can that.